# Disable ipv6 in Opera? (windows)

Tags: windows, ipv6, opera

How can i disable ipv6 in Opera? Windows version.

Disabling ipv6 in Windows or using other browser are not acceptable options.

Comment: out of curiosity: why?

Comment: To keep opera traffic out of ipv6 tunnel.

Comment: adhoc idea: you might succeed by using a ipv4-only-proxy.

Comment: I can do that if there's no other option, as a matter of fact i have such installed already, but would need to run another instance without ipv6 support. However it'd be a lot cleaner to set it in Opera alone...

Comment: Actually it wouldn't help because i couldn't proxy Opera's mail client traffic with the solution i have.

Comment: You can't. There is no such setting in Opera v12 or earlier - and I doubt it that there is such a setting in the "new Opera" v18.
Maybe you can block certain traffic from Opera using your Firewall (I don't think I can with the one I have but it's a thought)? There may be app specific settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opera does not have the feature a solution could be forcebindip

http://old.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/

```
ForceBindIP.exe -i 192.168.1.25 "C:\opera.exe"
```

where 192.168.1.25 is the ip of the interface you want to use

This application redirect any connection to a specific interface and keep it there.

Just replace all your opera shortcut to point them to forcebindip

As this program is source closed you could be sceptical in a perspective of using it all the time, i personally disassembled it and checked every action and it seem that it's a clean application.

Comment: Interesting possibility.